# Assign a rule with a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I need to assign a rule with a column but this column is `int` not a `UDDT`

I know how to assign a UDDT with a rule .. I need to assign a rule with a table column with `int` datatype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain I know what you are asking, but if I needed to create a 'rule' and assign it to a column, I would probably consider using a Check Constraint and not a user defined data type.

You can read more about [Check Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx).

Comment: simply how to attach a rule with a column ? :-)

Comment: @Sudantha - What do you consider a 'rule' to be?

Comment: @Sudantha - Well, I'm still not clear on what you want, but if I had to guess, I'd say you should explore a check constraint.

Comment: CREATE RULE is deprecated anyway http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx